# Родительский блок всегда шире дочернего. Как исправить?

Tags: css, css3

Нужно, чтобы элементы `li` были такого же размера, как и элементы `a`, но они почему-то шире на несколько пикселей. Более того, почему-то `ul` тоже больше `li` на то же самое количество пикселей. Как это исправить?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #000!important;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none!important;
}

.pricheta {
  color: #007bff!important;
}

.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #007bff;
}

.navigation .pricheta-logo {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}

.navigation>.menu-icon {
  font-size: 56px;
  color: #00b7ff!important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  display: none;
}

.navigation>.navigation-list {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.navigation>.navigation-list>.navigation-item {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navigation>.navigation-list>.navigation-item>a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}

.navigation>.navigation-list>.navigation-item>.navigation-link:hover {
  background: #00b7ff;
  color: #fff!important;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <nav class="navigation bg-white">
    <a class="pricheta-logo pricheta" href="#">pricheta</a>
    <i class="menu-icon fa fa-bars"></i>
    <ul class="navigation-list">
      <li class="navigation-item"><a class="navigation-link" href="#">Портфолию работ</a></li>
      <li class="navigation-item"><a class="navigation-link" href="#">Примеры виджетов</a></li>
      <li class="navigation-item"><a class="navigation-link" href="#">Резюме</a></li>
      <li class="navigation-item"><a class="navigation-link" href="#">Связаться со мной</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Что-то фигня с форматированием комментариев - в таком виде они абсолютно бесполезны.

Comment: @Qwertiy, все дело в том, что если этих комментариев не будет, тогда html переведет переход на следующую строку между тегами `<li>` в пробел. Так как у меня при наведении задний фон меняется, это критично. Комментарии спасают. Снизу скриншот, чтобы понять, о чем я говорю


https://ibb.co/r6ZKK6q

Можете сами удалить комментарии и посмотреть

Comment: Я в курсе, но при том, как комментарии расставлены в вопросе, этот пробел тоже есть. А вот в ответе они действительно работают.

Comment: @Qwertiy. Упс. Да, Вы правы. Дело в том, что когда я вставлял код на сайт, я нажал на кнопку "Привести в порядок" и оригинальный код был нарушен. Спасибо за поправку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из display: inline-block, могут появляться данные отступы, я бы советовал использовать flex, я переделал немножечко ваш пример и у меня нету никаких лишних пикселей.
[codepen](https://codepen.io/Ercogx/pen/zYOMgdN)

```
.navigation>.navigation-list {
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
}
.navigation>.navigation-list>.navigation-item>a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Все дело в том, что если дочерние элементы все отображаются как `inline-block`, то родительский становится чуть-чуть выше и шире сам по себе. Решается проблема простым переходом на отображение через `block`. Код пришлось полностью переделать, но теперь всё работает. Снизу оставлю код, вдруг кому-нибудь полезно будет.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
*{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 color: #000!important;
 background: #fff;
 overflow: hidden;
}
a:hover{
 text-decoration: none!important;
}
.pricheta{
 color: #007bff!important;
}
.navigation{
 border-bottom: 1px solid #00b7ff;
}
.navigation > .menu-icon{
 font-size: 56px;
    color: #00b7ff!important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}
.navigation > .navigation-list{
 margin: 0;
}
.navigation > .navigation-list > .navigation-item{
 display: block;
 max-width: 300px;
    float: left;
}
.navigation > .navigation-list > .navigation-item > a{
 padding: 15px 25px;
 display: block;
 font-size: 20px;
}
.navigation > .navigation-list > .navigation-item > .navigation-link:hover{
 background: #00b7ff;
 color: #fff!important;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
 <nav class="navigation bg-white">
  <i class="menu-icon fa fa-bars"></i>
  <ul class="navigation-list">
    <li class="navigation-item"><a class="pricheta-logo pricheta" href="#">pricheta</a></li><!--
   --><li class="navigation-item"><a class="navigation-link" href="#">Портфолию работ</a></li><!--
   --><li class="navigation-item"><a class="navigation-link" href="#">Примеры виджетов</a></li><!--
   --><li class="navigation-item"><a class="navigation-link" href="#">Резюме</a></li><!--
   --><li class="navigation-item"><a class="navigation-link" href="#">Связаться со мной</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header>
```